# How two side drawer should not overlap

Tags: reactjs

[image]
I have created a two side drawer and on a click of a button 2nd side drawer should open but when I open other side drawer the first side drawer is getting overlap (it is getting hide behind 2nd drawer), please let me know how can I stop this, when 2nd side drawer is opened the first side drawer should slide to left side

Comment: You can give a z-index to the first side drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-index. There are multiple ways of implementing this. You can have a second side drawer as a child of the first. In the current case I see you're managing them separate so here's the code on how to do it.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.first {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 99;
  background: red;
}


.second {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-left: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    first side drawer
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    Second Side drawer  
  </div>
</div>
```